# remap key to `selectNextSuggestion` fails

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is my keymap. The second re-map works fine. `ctrl+x` works as cursorDown.
But I can't get it to select the next item in a suggestion. It just exits the dropdown and moves the cursor. As if the first mapping does not exist.
This seems like it should work. Am I missing some magic?

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key":"ctrl+x",
        "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key":"ctrl+x",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "args": {
            "to":"down",
            "by": "line",
            "value": 1,
        },
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    },
]
```

The `when` clause looks to be exactly the same as `downArrow` for the same command.

I'm running version 1.76.2 on linux. Fresh install. No extensions, no other keys mapped, no settings changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the order of your two keybindings.  Why?  Because keybindings are evaluated from the bottom of the file upwards.

With your order `textInputFocus` evaluates to true, so the `cursorMove` command is executed whether the suggestWidget is visible or not.